# Google "Eddysone" Beacons - which capabilities for prompting users on devices?

Tags: android, ios, eddystone

I am trying to read up on beacon technologies (new area for me) - and select one or two technologies to use for Android and iOS. I have begun investigating Google Beacons "EddyStone" and Google's related technologies Proximity Beacon, Nearby Notifications and Nearby Messages.

...

If I understand it correctly, using "Google Beacons" you can register and associate beacon IDs to your app ID. If the Android user then walks by with bluetooth/BLE enabled (but not app installed) they can get a prompt to download the app. I can understand how this works on Android since Google controls Android OS (and Chrome) and can maintain a server with registered Beacons and their associated actions and app IDs. So far so good.

...

However, I do not understand if and how this will also work on iOS. My research indiciates it may work if the iOS user has Chrome installed or other apps that respond to Eddystone beacons - however, it will not be supported "out of the box" on most iOS phones - is that correctly understood?

...

However, assuming the user has an Eddystone beacon enabled app running in background - can my beacon prompt to download the app? (Or alternatively prompt an URL to a page that detects user agent and opens Google Play / iTunes store app link which I already have to handle QR code scans)

...

Using above Google technologies and Eddystone, can I take it a step further:

If the user passes by a beacon with BLE enabled and my app is not running/started, but installed can I have my app:

- Launched on Android (yes?)
- Launched on iOS (no?)
- Launched on iOS if already running in background (yes?)
- Monitoring for beacons on android (no?)
- Monitoring for beacons on android if already running in background (yes?)
- Monitoring for beacons on ios (no?)
- Monitoring for beacons on ios if already running in background (yes, but less precision?)

In parentheses I have inserted answers I found through Eddystone FAQ: https://kontakt.io/blog/eddystone-faq/

This would mean that a present, it would not be possible to use Eddystone beacons to automatically notify users with offers / text messages as they walk around a shop - at least not on iOS - and at least not without the user already having started the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis us essentially correct.  A few specific clarifications:

- On iOS before your custom app is installed, a user may be prompted to install only if they have installed Chrome (rare), activated the Chrome Today iOS widget (rarer still) and then opted in to beacon notifications.
- On iOS there is no mechanism for Eddystone to launch a non-running app.  For that you must use iBeacon.
- On iOS background detections on Eddystone are slow (many minutes) vs seconds under ideal conditions with iBeacon.
- On iOS you cannot automatically bring an app to the foreground from the background.  The closest you can get is to send a local notification to the user, and if the user taps the notification it will bring the app to the foreground.
- On Android it is possible to monitor for Eddystone beacons even if your app is not running (from a visible user perspective at least) by using a third party tool like the open source [Android Beacon Library manage background scanning.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html)